# How do I upgrade open-vm-tools to 12.3.5 on an internet isolated server

Tags: upgrade, security, vmware-tools

I am required to upgrade to open-vm-tools 12.3.5 to resolve CVE-2023-34058.
My few Ubuntu servers are isolated from the internet so "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" are not an option.
I'm running 20.04 and 22.04

How do I do the upgrade from just the "open-vm-tools-12.3.5-22544099.tar.gz" file?